# Vuetify Multiple <v-app> on the same page causes with menus and dropdowns

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, micro-frontend, single-spa

Iam working on micro-frontend using single-spa, vue and vuetify, i have multiple vue app as micro frontend, so each app has v-app, bcoz of this vuetify menus, dropdowns are not working properly when clicking outside a micro-frontend app.

below is the similar issue,
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4931

NOTE :

**vuetify version : 2.4.0,
vue version : 2.6.11**

Comment: I do not think Vuetify allows more than 1 v-app on the page. Have you tried https://github.com/DJanoskova/Vuidget or some other way to incapsulate your SPAs into separate WebComponents so that each SPA has its own shadow DOM and CSS scoping?

Comment: thanks @IVOGELOV no i havent tried yet..will give a try

Comment: We are facing the same problem using WebComponents. 
Did you solve your Problem?